# having some beginner problems with my replay def only replaying once for a number guesser

Tags: python

so I will run the number guesser and I will get the number than it will ask if I want to replay it and I put "y" to replay it but then once I get through it again and it asks if I want to play again it stops even if I say yes

```
import random
flag = 0

def Game():
    print("Welcome to number guesser. I'm thinking of a number from 1-100 try to guess it in as few trys as possible.")
    targetnumber = random.randint(0,101)#seting up a randome number as targetnumber 
    amount = 0
    flag = 0
    while flag == 0:
        print("type an integer from 1 to 100 and press enter.")
        
        userguess = int(input()) #taking inputs
        
        if userguess > targetnumber:
            print("Too high")
            amount += 1

        if userguess < 0:
            print("enter a positive integer")
        
        if userguess < targetnumber:
            print("Too low")
            amount += 1

        if userguess == targetnumber:
            print("Correct!") #guess respones
            print("you took " +str(amount)+" guesses to guess the right number")
            flag = 1
def replay():
    print("welcome")
    print("do you want to play again y/n")
    userguess = input()
    if userguess == "y":
        Game()
    if userguess == "n":
        print("goodbye")
            
            
Game()
replay()
```

Answer (score 1):

My advice is to use a different approach to the logic. Once you play for the second time there is no call to replay() function and the process will end.
For example you can change replay() function to:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("welcome")
    while True:
        print("do you want to play again y/n")
        userguess = input()
        if userguess == "y":
            Game()
        else:
            print('goodbye')
            break
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's a problem of missing new lines before the function definition?
Look at this question [Blank lines convention](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2953250/python-pep8-blank-lines-convention)